# SQL query grouping dynamic value

Tags: sql

I need your help how to summarize from grouping dataset.

| docno | acc |
| --- | --- |
| doc1 | A |
| doc1 | B |
| doc2 | B |
| doc2 | C |
| doc3 | A |
| doc3 | B |
| doc4 | A |
| doc4 | B |

The output number 1, I want to expect is:

| acc_combined | docno |
| --- | --- |
| A;B | doc1 |
| B;C | doc2 |
| A;B | doc3 |
| A;B | doc4 |

The output number 2:

| acc_combined | count |
| --- | --- |
| A;B | 3 |
| B;C | 1 |

Column acc_combined can be dynamic value such as D;E, A;B;C, C;D;E, A;E, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in SQL or python or R? Or are you looking for a SQL solution using either python or R accessors? Are you accepting of solutions that are all native R/python?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output you're looking for, where StackOverflow is a table formatted according to the first table you provided (accept I accidentally misspelled acc as accn, my bad):

```sql
WITH First_CTE AS (
    SELECT docno,
        STRING_AGG(accn, ';') AS acc_combined
    FROM StackOverflow
    GROUP BY docno
) SELECT acc_combined,
        COUNT(docno) AS count
FROM First_CTE
GROUP BY acc_combined
```